# Query to order data while maintaining grouping?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a request which I can accomplish in code but am wondering if it is at all possible do do on SQL alone. I have a products table that has a Category column and a Price column. What I want to achieve is all of the products grouped together by Category, and then ordered by the cheapest to most expensive in both the category and all the categories combined. So for example :

```
Category      |    Price
--------------|---------------------
Basin         |    500
Basin         |    700
Basin         |    750
Accessories   |    550
Accessories   |    700
Accessories   |    1000
Bath          |    700
```

As you can see the cheapest item is a basin for 500, then an Accessory for 550 then a bath for 700. So I need the categories of products to be sorted by their cheapest item, and then each category itself in turn to be sorted cheapest to most expensive.

I have tried partitioning, grouping sets ( which i know nothing about ) but still no luck so eventually resorted to my strength ( C# ) but would prefer to do it straight in SQL if possible. One last side note : This query is hit quite often so performance is key so if possible i would like to avoid temp tables / cursors etc

Comment: Can you provide an example of the resultset you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `MIN()` with a window ([`OVER`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)) makes it *clearest* what the intent is:

```
declare @t table (Category varchar(19) not null,Price int not null)
insert into @t (Category,Price) values
('Basin',500),
('Basin',700),
('Basin',750),
('Accessories',550),
('Accessories',700),
('Accessories',1000),
('Bath',700)

;With FindLowest as (
    select *,
        MIN(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Category) as Lowest
    from
        @t
)
select * from FindLowest
order by Lowest,Category,Price
```

If two categories share the same lowest price, this will still keep the two categories separate and sort them alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select... 
Order by category, price desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you do not need GROUP BY clause in your query. If I got your goal correctly, you can try by substituting actual categories in your ORDER BY clause with the minimum price per category inside the subquery.That will allow you getting all the categories sequential, i.e. not    Basin - 500; Accessories - 550, but everything for Basin first. After that, you can group by ordinary Price inside each category.

```
SELECT *
FROM products p
ORDER BY 
  (SELECT MIN(Price) FROM products p2 WHERE p2.Category=p.Category
  ),
  Price;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.category,p.price 
FROM products p,(select category,min(price) mn from products group by category order by mn) tab1
WHERE p.category=tab1.category
GROUP BY p.category,p.price,tab1.mn
order by tab1.mn,p.category;
```

Is this what you want?